# how would i print the contents of a div tag holding receipt details?

Tags: php, jquery

i am working on a project an was wondering how i would print contents of a div holding receipt details. or should i use a pdf?
I will really appreciate the help.

Comment: You can print using javascript `document.getElementById("myDiv").print();`

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can open the div content in popup and do document.print()

It will work fine for all browser